# Выпадающий список на кнопке в CSS Hover и IE от 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hover

Все вроде работает на Chrome, попытался посмотреть IE 11 версии - вроде бы hover срабатывает (если top и left = 0 блока menu, хотя мне нужно под кнопкой показывать), но display и position при этом ведут себя как то странно (не отображается блок menu целиком если position absolute)

Как добиться одинакового поведения?

[Ссылка работающего кода](https://jsfiddle.net/gLw2xqvb/9/)

сам блок описываю как

```
.memu_title {
            display: block;
            position:relative;
}

 .menu {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
}
.memu_title:hover .menu {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
        }

<button class="memu_title" onmouseout="">Меню
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a target="content" onclick="" href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
            <li><a target="content" onclick="" href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>
            <li><a target="content" onclick="" href="#">Ссылка 3</a></li>
        </ul>
</button>
```

Comment: В последнее время сформировалась положительная тенденция - если юзер использует IE, посылать его ставить нормальный браузер. Про IE уже давно пора забыть, сам Микрософт это признал.

Answer (score 0):

нужно просто добавить

```
.memu_title{
   overflow: visible;
}
```